# CSS import in React Component not working in Electron app

Tags: css, reactjs, gulp, electron, babeljs

First of all, I want to say sorry because I feel like I lack some theorical background for this problem, but right now I am stuck so here I am.

I want to set up an Electron app with just the usual main.js entry point which handles BrowserWindow creation. I want to create multiple, different windows, so the boilerplates I found on the Internet are no good for me.

So, my main.js creates a window by using an .html file that uses a script tag to add its renderer, that just sets up a React component like this:

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
const ReactComponent = require('path/to/component').default;

window.onload = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<ReactComponent />, document.getElementById('my-component'));
};
```

My component is very basic so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import './ReactComponent.css';

class ReactComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ReactComponent">
                some text
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ReactComponent;
```

And the .css is even simpler:

```
.ReactComponent {background-color: red;}
```

I used Gulp + Babel to compile my code, and everything works well until I add that

> import './ReactComponent.css';

Which throws this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Reading the .css file.

Here is my .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

And my gulpfile.js:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const gulp = require('gulp');
const maps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const css = require('gulp-css');
const path = require('path');

/* Build */

gulp.task('build-css', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
        .pipe(maps.init())
        .pipe(css())
        .pipe(maps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/src'));
});

gulp.task('build-js', () => {
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.jsx', '!src/**/*.test.js'])
        .pipe(maps.init())
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(maps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/src'));
});

gulp.task('build-main-js', () => {
    return gulp.src('main.js')
        .pipe(maps.init())
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(maps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});


gulp.task('build', gulp.series('build-css', 'build-js', 'build-main-js'));


/* Copy */

gulp.task('copy-html', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
        .pipe(maps.init())
        .pipe(maps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/src'));
});

gulp.task('copy-assets', () => {
    return gulp.src('assets/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets'));
});

gulp.task('copy', gulp.parallel('copy-html', 'copy-assets'));



/* Execute */

const cmd = (name) => path.resolve(__dirname) + '\\node_modules\\.bin\\' + name + '.cmd';
const args = (more) => Array.isArray(more) ? ['.'].concat(more) : ['.'];
const exit = () => process.exit();

gulp.task('start', gulp.series('copy', 'build', () => {
    return spawn(cmd('electron'), args(), { stdio: 'inherit' }).on('close', exit);
}));


gulp.task('release', gulp.series('copy', 'build', () => {
    return spawn(cmd('electron-builder'), args(), { stdio: 'inherit' }).on('close', exit);
}));

gulp.task('test', gulp.series('copy', 'build', () => {
    return spawn(cmd('jest'), args(), { stdio: 'inherit' }).on('close', exit);
}));
```

At this point I don't even know anymore what the problem is... Please send help!

Many thanks!

Comment: You're using an old fashioned slow gulp script which scrapes src for css, it doesn't expect it to be imported in the JS files. I would suggest burning it all and just using webpack with css plugins.

Comment: Thank you, I guessed so. I am not very skilled with Webpack, and I could not find any example that matches my case (integration with multiple Electron windows) since every one needed a single .html as entry point... Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry not familiar with Electron, I understand there are some extra steps as you said. The first few links here look promising - https://www.google.com/search?q=create+react+app+for+electron&rlz=1C1GCEB_en&oq=react-create-app+for+e%3Bectron

Comment: Actually I just needed your small input and I managed to make it work! I studied package.json and webpack.config.js from https://github.com/Thomascountz/react-electron-webpack , duplicated entry-points and outputs as shown in the webpack documentation and it seems to work! Thank you very much :)